# ニューラルネットワークに入力したx,y座標がsinカーブよりも上の領域に位置するか、下に位置するかを学習させたい

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy, anaconda

python3でニューラルネットワークに入力したx,y座標がsinカーブよりも上の領域に位置するか、下に位置するかを学習させるためのコードを書いているところですがエラーが発生してどうにも変えても前に進めず、壁にぶち当たりました。

valueErrorが型の違いらしい？ということを調べて予想しているのですが、果たしてどうでしょうか？
もしコードの方にも間違いがありましたら、教えて頂けたら大変嬉しいです。

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-628624d42e80> in <module>()
    126     plt.plot(

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-628624d42e80> in <module>()
    126     plt.plot(X, sin_data, linestyle="dashed")
    127     plt.scatter(x_1, y_1, marker="+")
--> 128     plt.scatter(x_2, y_2, marker="=")
    129     plt.show()
    130 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, nX, sin_data, linestyle="dashed")
    127     plt.scatter(x_1, y_1, marker="+")
--> 128     plt.scatter(x_2, y_2, marker="=")
    129     plt.show()
    130 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3355                          vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha,
   3356                          linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts,
-> 3357                          edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
   3358     finally:
   3359         ax._hold = washold

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1708                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1709                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1710             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1711         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1712         if pre_doc is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4017         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4018         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4019             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4020 
   4021         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

***`以下ソースコード`***

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(-1.0, 1.1, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.1, 0.1)

input_data = []
correct_data = []
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        input_data.append([x, y])
        if y < np.sin(np.pi * x):
            correct_data.append([0, 1])
        else:
            correct_data.append([1, 0])

n_data = len(correct_data)

input_data = np.array(input_data)
correct_data = np.array(correct_data)

n_in = 2
n_mid = 6
n_out = 2

wb_width = 0.01
eta = 0.1
epoch = 101
interval = 10

class MiddleLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = 1/(1+np.exp(-u))

    def backward(self, grad_y):
        delta = grad_y * (1-self.y)*self.y

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


class OutputLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = np.exp(u)/np.sum(np.exp(u), axis=1, keepdims=True)

    def backward(self, t):
        delta = self.y - t

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


middle_layer = MiddleLayer(n_in, n_mid)
output_layer = OutputLayer(n_mid, n_out)

sin_data = np.sin(np.pi * X)
for i in range(epoch):

    index_random = np.arange(n_data)
    np.random.shuffle(index_random)


total_error = 0
x_1 = []
y_1 = []
x_2 = []   
y_2 = [] 

for idx in index_random:

    x = input_data[idx]
    t = correct_data[idx]

    middle_layer.forward(x.reshape(1, 2))
    output_layer.forward(middle_layer.y)

    output_layer.backward(t.reshape(1, 2))
    middle_layer.backward(output_layer.grad_x)

    middle_layer.update(eta)
    output_layer.update(eta)

    if i%interval == 0:

        y = output_layer.y.reshape(-1)

        total_error += np.sum(t * np.log(y + 1e-7))

        if y[0] > y[1]:
            x_1.append(x[0])
            y_1.append(x[1])
        else:
            x_2.append(x[0])
            x_2.append(x[1])


if i%interval == 0:

    plt.plot(X, sin_data, linestyle="dashed")
    plt.scatter(x_1, y_1, marker="+")
    plt.scatter(x_2, y_2, marker="=")
    plt.show()

    print("Epoch:" + str(i) + "/" + str(epoch),
          "Error:" + str(total_error/n_data))
```

Answer (score 3):

`x_2` と `y_2` のサイズが異なることが原因です（ `print(len(x_2), len(y_2))` と実行すると、それぞれ460, 0と表示されます）。おそらく、以下の部分で誤記しているようです。

```
if y[0] > y[1]:
    x_1.append(x[0])
    y_1.append(x[1])
else:
    x_2.append(x[0])
    x_2.append(x[1]) # <- y_2.append では？
```

Comment: @PicoSushiさん本当に編集とお返事がくることに勇気付けられました。書かない方が良いとコメントのヘルプで言われてしまいましたが、やはり伝えずにはいられない感謝が込み上げてくるので我慢できませんでした。
大変ありがとうございます。

つきまして、勇気とやる気を取り戻し、再び再確認した所、



        total_error += np.sum(t * np.log(y + 1e-7))　# <-         total_error += - np.sum(t * np.log(y + 1e-7)) ここの交差エントロピー誤差の式を間違えているところを発見できました。


            x_2.append(x[1])  　　　　　# <- y_2で間違いないです。

Comment: @松本文音 さん、解決に繋がったようでよかったです。この回答で大丈夫な場合、承認済みとしてマークをお願いします。今後もスタックオーバーフローをご活用ください。